# ApacheAirFlow: Inside of a task, what should be used instead of now()?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am looking at best practices in Apache Airflow and it says

"*The Python datetime now() function gives the current datetime object. This function should never be used inside a task, especially to do the critical computation, as it leads to different outcomes on each run. It’s fine to use it, for example, to generate a temporary log*."
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html

It does not say what should someone use instead of now()?  What should I use if I am trying to insert a loadtimestamp value? what should I use instead of now()?

This is a best practices question, I am new to airflow so not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Airflow macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html).

The reasoning is that, as explained in the doc, `now()` generate different values every time you invoke it. In ETL/workflow management usually you want timestamp to be consistent across jobs so downstream tasks can find/handled upstream task output.
Think for example about a case where upstream task is writing output to S3 in specific path `/timestamp/file.csv`. if you generated timestamp with `now()` then downstream task won't be able to find that path because running `now()` in downstream will generate different value. In general this can be avoidable using Xcom (push the path to Xcom then downstream can read it but the better solution is using Airflow macros).

For example if path is : `/{{ ts_nodash }}/file.csv` that is a path that
is consistent for all tasks in the DAG and no information needs to be shared between tasks.

Answer (score -3):

When it comes to managing timestamp values within your Apache Airflow DAGs, it's crucial to consider the principles of consistency and reusability. The documentation's advice against using datetime.now() inside tasks is well-founded, as it can lead to different outcomes on each run, causing discrepancies and potential issues.

To handle timestamp values effectively and follow best practices, you can leverage [Airflow's built-in macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/macros.html). One particularly useful macro is {{ ds }}, which provides the "execution date" of the current DAG run in the format "YYYY-MM-DD". This macro offers several benefits:

1. **Consistency**: By using {{ ds }}, you ensure that the timestamp value remains consistent across task executions within a DAG run. This is crucial for maintaining data integrity and enabling reproducibility.
2. **Backfilling and Reruns**: The use of {{ ds }} is highly beneficial when backfilling historical data or rerunning failed ETL jobs. When you re-run a task, Airflow automatically substitutes {{ ds }} with the corresponding date for that run, making it easy to reprocess or backfill specific time periods.
3. **Readable Naming Conventions**: Incorporating {{ ds }} into your task names or log messages helps you easily identify when a task was executed, enhancing the clarity of your logs and aiding troubleshooting. Good example is provided by @Elad `/{{ ds }}/file.csv` which is rendered as example `/2023-08-16/file.csv`

Still unclear? watch my detailed video here https://youtu.be/TxrGzLlsXdM?t=101